# How to avoid timeout making large CSV with python?

Tags: python, django, azure, csv, timeout

For a project, I need to implement a CSV export of a large database. My Django project is hosted on Azure and I get a timeout error every time...

I think I need to implement an asynchronous function or something.

I've tried async_to_sync and sync_to_async, start with Daphne server, StreamingHttpResponse...

Here is the code:

```
class Echo:
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """

    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def export_csv(request):
    try:
        # long task
        first_item, second_item, third_item = my_function(request.data)

        csv_tab = []
        csv_tab.append(build_headers())

        # long task
        for item in first_item:
            csv_tab.extend(build_lines(item, second_item, third_item))

        pseudo_buffer = Echo()

        writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer, delimiter=';')

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
            (writer.writerow(line) for line in csv_tab),
            content_type='text/csv',
            headers={
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'},
        )

        return response
    except Exception as identifier:
        LOGGER.exception(identifier)
        current = {
            'state': "failure",
            'reason': "server error",
        }
        print(identifier)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(current), status=500)
```

Comment: What do you consider to be a large database? How many rows is the CSV file?

Comment: More than 300000

Comment: If you're just pulling rows from a database then a `StreamingHttpResponse` should probably be good enough. How computationally intensive is `my_function`?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I'm not just pulling rows, there's a big processing part behind it, which makes the process long enough for Azure to not be happy...

Answer (score 0):

If your request takes a long time, you should use a background task library like `celery`.

Depending on the use case, you can email the result after the calculation or generate some kind of ID or token and redirect the user to an intermediate page that indicates whether processing is still in progress or the results are ready for download.

- https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html